# Karma & PhantomJS are not running reliable on TFS

Tags: angularjs, windows, tfs, phantomjs, karma-runner

I have a .NET Project with an Angular Frontend building on a TFS Server.
I've set up a gulp task for CI which starts karma with the singleRun flag set and PhantomJS as a browser.
This works most of the time but sometimes it isn't running the tests.
PhantomJS seems to start and connect to Karma but then it times out.

I thought it was because the server is too slow but it has a timeout of 200000ms and still fails sometimes.

I've already set proxy-type none for PhantomJS and debug logs are indicating that it starts to request files from the karma server but then it suddenly stops.

Has anyone experienced a similar behaviour and knows how to fix this?

```
2016-06-14T08:07:45.5637194Z [10:07:45] Starting 'test-ci'...
2016-06-14T08:07:50.4702112Z [BABEL] Note: The code generator has deoptimised the styling of "" as it exceeds the max of "100KB".
2016-06-14T08:07:50.6108309Z [BABEL] Note: The code generator has deoptimised the styling of "" as it exceeds the max of "100KB".
2016-06-14T08:07:55.6735654Z 14 06 2016 10:07:55.672:INFO [karma]: Karma v0.13.22 server started at http://localhost:9876/
2016-06-14T08:07:55.6735654Z 14 06 2016 10:07:55.672:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS
2016-06-14T08:07:56.4650516Z 14 06 2016 10:07:56.461:INFO [PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 8 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket /#I8LhurGp-Wft4vtBAAAA with id 32316983
2016-06-14T08:11:16.4785361Z 14 06 2016 10:11:16.478:WARN [PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 8 0.0.0)]: Disconnected (1 times), because no message in 200000 ms.
2016-06-14T08:11:16.4785361Z PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 8 0.0.0): Executed 0 of 0 DISCONNECTED (3 mins 20.018 secs / 0 secs)
2016-06-14T08:11:16.5097988Z [10:11:16] 'test-ci' errored after 3.5 min
2016-06-14T08:11:16.5097988Z [10:11:16] Error: Tests failed
```

Comment: Which build system are you using on TFS? vNext or XAML?

Comment: It seems there are something wrong with connection on the server. Moreover, according to your log. It's 200000ms not 200000s. **200000ms=200s**

Comment: But then it shouldn't be able to connect in the first place, right?
Ah yeah, forgot the m. 200000s would be over 2 days :D

Comment: Try the new build system.  Run the agent interactive (not as a service)